# A Typical Issue with login using Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Iam facing a typical issue with a form submit using Zend framework. Basically I have written a simple code to login a user, but this came out of the blue.

The code to show the form is pretty standard

$loginform = new Application_Form_Login();
        $loginform->setMethod('post');
        $loginform->setAction('login');
        $this->view->form = $loginform;

When I use my home page url as - http://localhost.ruin.com/public/

I get an exception

```
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (login)
Stack trace:

#0 C:\domains\ruin\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 C:\domains\ruin\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 C:\domains\ruin\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 C:\domains\ruin\public\index.php(27): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'login',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
  'username' => 'fsdf',
  'password' => 'fdsf',
  'submit' => 'submit',
)
```

However if I use the base url as http://localhost.ruin.com/public/index/ , the same code works perfectly.

I also know that its due to the fact that in first url the zend router is messing up the index controller with login since its not able to append the login action to the default index controller.

Do you guys think this is by design of Zend Framework and I shall have to forcefully send my users to this url
http://localhost.ruin.com/public/index/ whenever they hit the home page or is there a way I can make my code work with
http://localhost.ruin.com/public/

Any suggestions?

Comment: post your route's & .htaccess file contents

Comment: What happens if you try to access /public/login/index ?

Comment: @ishkumar - No custom routes, .htaccess is the default which the zend tool generates. No change made to either of them.

Comment: @keyne, /public/login/index wont work as expected as there is NO controller called as login, the controller is index and the action is login.

Comment: could you please try to add `resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/public"` to your application.ini , and let's know ....

Comment: Hard to understand your problem at the first time. It's all about relative urls. So you need to use the url helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
$form->setAction('/public/index/login');
```

Ridiculously verbose answer follows: ;-)

One point of confusion is the use of the term "action".

With regard to a *form*, "action" refers to the action attribute:

```
<form action="/url/at/which/the/form/will/be/processed" method="post">
```

This is the action be referred to when you call `$form->setAction()` method. The key point is that this must be a *URL*, and the application has to have routing in place that maps this URL to a (controller, action) pair.

Which brings up the other way that the term "action" is used: as a shorthand name for a method on a controller. For example, the action named "smile" maps to the method `smileAction()` on the controller.

So, in your case, the issue is one of getting your form's `setAction()` call in-sync with the routing that's in place for the app.

By specifying the URL 'login' as the form's action, you are providing a *relative* URL, so the browser will interpret this as relative to the URL that appears in the browser's location bar. When you browse to the page but leave off the "index" portion of the URL, then the default routing in the framework views "login" as the controller. Since you have no `LoginController`, the request craps out.

So your `IndexController` could look like:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->form = $this->_getForm();
    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        $form = $this->_getForm();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
                // All cool. Process your form,
                // probably with a redirect afterwords to
                // clear the POST.
            }
        }

        // Still alive?
        // Then it was either not a post request or the form was invalid.
        // In either case, set the form in the view
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    /**
    * A helper method to keep the form creation DRY
    */
    protected function _getForm()
    {
        $loginform = new Application_Form_Login();
        $loginform->setMethod('post');

        // Points the form to the IndexController::loginAction();
        $loginform->setAction('/public/index/login');
        return $loginform;
    }
}
```

The upshot is that the setAction() call needs a URL that the router can map to a controller/action pair knows how to process the post.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the URL of your action like this:

If you're on the view

```
$this->form->setAction($this->url(array('params here or'), 'the route name'));
```

If you're on the controller

```
$form->setAction($this->_helper->url(array('params or...'), 'the route name'));
```

or

```
$form->setAction($this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/index/login');
```

See this related question:

[Zend Form SetAction Using Named Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288901/zend-form-setaction-using-named-routes)

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one, but in the controller the action helper should be used instead view helper.

Comment: Thanks @takeshin I've add your recomendation.

Answer (score -1):

The thing you should realize first is that the "public" folder in your example should be the web root (or DocumentRoot). Once you set it up correctly, you'll see that you can access your site using http://localhost.ruin.com, and I'm quite sure that your login form will work without any problem.

Refer to http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html for more information.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the directory structure.